# Putting a check for variable type when using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a small program (student, though not an assignment for class...but rather a play on a previous assignment).  Previously for class, while learning `do/while` loops, I wrote a program that prompted a user to input integers.  When the user typed in 0, it served to get out of the loop, and then outputted the sum of the squares of all the integers typed.

Example output (double spaced for line breaks):

Type an integer: 3

Type an integer: 0

The sum of the squares is 9

My goal now is to take it a step farther.  As written, the program crashes if the user types in anything other than an integer.  I have been playing around trying to find ways to allow the user to type in other forms of values, without having it crash.  In referencing the code below (which is the program at the moment that does crash at any value sans `ints`), I tried putting in variations of if statements with the `console.hasNextInt()` method.  Yet my attempts in this would cause an error that `number` in the `do/while` test may not have been referenced.

Can anyone offer me any tips?  It would be appreciated.

```
    public static void userInterface() {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number;
    int numberSquared;
    int squaredOutput = 0;

    do {
        System.out.print("Type an integer (0 to quit): ");
        number = console.nextInt(); 

        if (number > 0 || number < 0) {
            numberSquared = number * number;
            squaredOutput += numberSquared;
        }
    } while (number != 0);


    System.out.println("The sum of the squares is " + squaredOutput);
}
```

Comment: When they enter a non-int do you want the program to finish? or to ignore and continue the loop?

Comment: Excuse my nascent/verbose sentences.  Ideally, I am hoping that if the user enters a char, string, double, etc., the program will not crash, but instead alert the user that he/she has inputted an invalid response, and then ask them to try again.

Comment: @logan-murphy's answer got removed ... so, to recap, just put a value in `int number` before your `do...while` loop. Then, look at the [Scanner api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) you'll notice that Scanner has a number of `next...` type methods. Generally, just use `.next()` or `.nextLine()` and you can cast it to whatever you like, to make more general solutions that can accept more than integers.

Comment: Much thanks.  I will follow this and hopefully find my answer.  Thank you to all of you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `console.nextInt();` which only takes the next int.

You can use: `console.nextLine();`.

It would allow your program to accept a string and you can parse it into an Int when necessary:

```
try { 
        number=Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine()); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        System.out.println("Please input an Integer");
    }
```

Comment: This is close to correct. You probably need a continue; in your catch block. And set number to something non-zero first.

Comment: The downvoted answer did answer the OP's problem. OP just needs to intialize "number" outside of the `do...while` loop.

Comment: @ProgrammerDan `Excuse my nascent/verbose sentences. Ideally, I am hoping that if the user enters a char, string, double, etc., the program will not crash, but instead alert the user that he/she has inputted an invalid response, and then ask them to try again.` -OP

Comment: @Cruncher 'twas added after my original comment, I cannot answer what will be asked, only what has been :).

Answer (score 1):

Just use this function

```
public static int next(String message) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(message);
        try {
            return new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now this is the best answer. Was about to write mine with this inlined. Probably better as a method anyway

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I should read the entire question from now on

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your code. When you use `console.nextInt()` and the scanner try to parse every string as Integer. Better solution is to use `console.nextLine()` and by your own parse it to your number and catch exception that might be thrown if that string is not parsable as any number that you want.
 simply it might look like this.

```
String yourValue = console.nextLine();
try{
  int value = Integer.parseInt(yourValue);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
  System.out.println("watch out this value is unparsable!");
}
```